# Printing with RawPrinterHelper for all international languages

Tags: vb.net

I want to print this string with Russian (Cyrillic) characters using `RawPrinterHelper` :

"Клиент:"

How can i print this ?

With default `RawPrinterHelper` settings i am not able to print.

Comment: What is your current code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually this all are new thing for me , i try with some encoding, but not working at all. if you have any specific idea then please share so i can try or lets see what result come.

Comment: What do you mean by "default settings" then? Where are your attempts failing? Please read up on the subject, try it on your own, and come back to SO with a specific question. Good luck!

Comment: "default setting" means i am not try by adding new thing in rawPrinterHelper , whatever the function provided by it i used that.